# Is there a way to draw shapes using javascript in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, graphics

I just completed AP CSP, and I learned how to draw shapes using javascript in Code HS:
[How I've been told to draw shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxynP.png).

How would I do something like this in VS Code or any other IDE?

Any code I tried from the internet that involved graphics didn't work.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VSCode has any built-in nor extensions for Javascript graphical computation. Nether do any IDE's that I know of can just have graphics of just plain Javascript. I think something like **JSFiddle** could work and you could use `document.create` for any of the elements you want if you really don't wanna use HTML. You could also **try using a live server with DOM Javascript** but then it would require an HTML file. Also many other IDEs have live server add-ons/extensions or even built in.